# Python Threading Issue, Is this Right?

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, asynchronous, dns, queue

I am attempting to make a few thousand dns queries. I have written my script to use python-adns. I have attempted to add threading and queue's to ensure the script runs optimally and efficiently.

However, I can only achieve mediocre results. The responses are choppy/intermittent. They start and stop, and most times pause for 10 to 20 seconds. 
    tlock = threading.Lock()#printing to screen

```
def async_dns(i):

    s = adns.init()
    for i in names:

        tlock.acquire()

        q.put(s.synchronous(i, adns.rr.NS)[0])
        response = q.get()
        q.task_done()

        if response == 0:
            dot_net.append("Y")
            print(i + ", is Y")
        elif response == 300:
            dot_net.append("N")
            print(i + ", is N")

        tlock.release()


q = queue.Queue()

threads = []

for i in range(100):
    t = threading.Thread(target=async_dns, args=(i,))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
    print(threads)
```

I have spent countless hours on this. I would appreciate some input from expedienced pythonista's . Is this a networking issue ? Can this bottleneck/intermittent responses be solved by switching servers ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the rest of the code? What's `names`? What's `tlock`? What's `dot_net`? It looks like maybe you're starting 100 threads that are all doing all the queries (instead of dividing up the work); you pass `i` but then never use it.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `Queue`? Maybe it's just a way to collect the results? (It looks like each thread adds its own things to the queue and then immediately marks them as complete.) Depending on what `tlock` is, could it be that all the threads are locking each other out while they do their DNS queries?

Comment: tlock = threading.Lock()

Comment: I am trying to start the thread send them out to get the response and the write the results to a list. Is 100 threads too much.

Comment: From my investigations, it seem the threads are duplicating task. How can I fix this issue

Comment: Each thread is definitely doing the same work (`for i in names:`), assuming every thread sees the same value of `names`. (You still haven't told us what `names` is.)

Answer (score 0):

Without answers to the questions, I asked in comments above, I'm not sure how well I can diagnose the issue you're seeing, but here are some thoughts:

1. It looks like each thread is processing all `names` instead of just a portion of them.
2. Your `Queue` seems to be doing nothing at all.
3. Your lock seems to guarantee that you actually only do one query at a time (defeating the purpose of having multiple threads).

Rather than trying to fix up this code, might I suggest using `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` instead? Below is a full working example. (You could use `adns` instead of `socket` if you want... I just couldn't easily get it installed and so stuck with the built-in `socket`.)

In my testing, I also sometimes see pauses; my assumption is that I'm getting throttled somewhere.

```
import itertools
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import socket
import string

def is_available(host):
    print('Testing {}'.format(host))
    try:
        socket.gethostbyname(host)
        return False
    except socket.gaierror:
        return True

# Test the first 1000 three-letter .com hosts
hosts = [''.join(tla) + '.com' for tla in itertools.permutations(string.ascii_lowercase, 3)][:1000]

with ThreadPool(100) as p:
    results = p.map(is_available, hosts)

for host, available in zip(hosts, results):
    print('{} is {}'.format(host, 'available' if available else 'not available'))
```